# browserify detect custom require()

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I want to use a custom `require()` function in my application. 
Namely I have node's standard `require()` and a custom one I wrote to require files starting from the root called `rootRequire()` which internally all it does is:

```
// rootRequire.js
var path = require('path');

var rootPath = __dirname;
global.rootRequire = function (modulePath) {
  var filepath = path.join(rootPath, modulePath);
  return require(filepath);
};

module.exports = rootRequire;
```

But even though `rootRequire()` internally uses node's `require()`, it does not pick up any files required through that method

Example:

```
require('rootRequire.js');
rootRequire('/A.js'); // server side it works, in the browser I get an error saying can't find module A.js
```

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this?

Comment: nope. started using webpack and it supports and bypassed the issue altogether

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, [this](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/377%5d) will answer your question on why it is not working on browser.

Quoting the owner's comment: "Browserify can only analyze static requires. It is not in the scope of browserify to handle dynamic requires".

Technically, you are trying to load files dynamically from a variable with your custom require. Obviously, node.js can handle that.

In case of browserify, all requires are statically loaded and packaged when you run the CLI to build the bundle.

HTH.

Comment: Note that webpack does allow for handling dynamic requires so that may be an option.

Answer (score 1):

What i recommend doing here is this:

First create a bundle to be required of anything you might use in `rootRequire()`.

Something like `browserify -r CURRENT_PATH/A.js -r CURRENT_PATH/B.js > rootRequirePackages.js`

Then, in your webpage, you can include both rootRequirePackages.js and your regular browserified file.

Comment: that really doesn't work as i use rootRequire everywhere and I don't want to keep track of where I used it or not

Comment: Maybe you can create a bundle of all the files in the project? :/
Also, why do you really need `rootRequire`? Couldn't you use `require('./A.js')`?

Comment: well i don't want to bother with relative require-ing files like require('../../../A.js'). It is hard to maintain and prone to a lot of errors. I'd much rather do rootRequire('lib/A.js'); everywhere

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps just use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) ? It's simple to set up and relatively easy to use.